# DocuSign: Rest API - ENVELOPE_IS_INCOMPLETE

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to send an envelope by using the DocuSign rest API. However I'm facing this error when using a template with an envelope:

```
{{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}

{"errorCode": "ENVELOPE_IS_INCOMPLETE",
"message": "The Envelope is not Complete. A Complete Envelope Requires Documents, Recipients, Tabs, and a Subject Line."}
```

This is my response JSON from the GET envelopes:

```
{
"status": "created",
"documentsUri": "/envelopes/9d3745dd-33e1-4b2a-a8ab-332d4f18c302/documents",
"recipientsUri": "/envelopes/9d3745dd-33e1-4b2a-a8ab-332d4f18c302/recipients",
"attachmentsUri": "/envelopes/9d3745dd-33e1-4b2a-a8ab-332d4f18c302/attachments",
"envelopeUri": "/envelopes/9d3745dd-33e1-4b2a-a8ab-332d4f18c302",
"emailSubject": "Test 1",
"emailBlurb": "Welcome!",
"envelopeId": "9d3745dd-33e1-4b2a-a8ab-332d4f18c302",
"signingLocation": "online",
"customFieldsUri": "/envelopes/9d3745dd-33e1-4b2a-a8ab-332d4f18c302/custom_fields",
"notificationUri": "/envelopes/9d3745dd-33e1-4b2a-a8ab-332d4f18c302/notification",
"enableWetSign": "true",
"allowMarkup": "false",
"allowReassign": "true",
"createdDateTime": "2022-08-01T05:58:51.1070000Z",
"lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-08-01T05:58:55.6830000Z",
"statusChangedDateTime": "2022-08-01T05:58:51.1070000Z",
"documentsCombinedUri": "/envelopes/9d3745dd-33e1-4b2a-a8ab-332d4f18c302/documents/combined",
"certificateUri": "/envelopes/9d3745dd-33e1-4b2a-a8ab-332d4f18c302/documents/certificate",
"templatesUri": "/envelopes/9d3745dd-33e1-4b2a-a8ab-332d4f18c302/templates",
"sender": {
    "userName": "test user",
    "userId": "63217fd2-612b-45e7-8d3d-b30b6984925a",
    "accountId": "257928273d",
    "email": "test.user@asj.com"
},
"purgeState": "unpurged",
"envelopeIdStamping": "true",
"is21CFRPart11": "false",
"signerCanSignOnMobile": "true",
"autoNavigation": "true",
"isSignatureProviderEnvelope": "false",
"hasFormDataChanged": "false",
"allowComments": "true",
"hasComments": "false",
"allowViewHistory": "true",
"envelopeMetadata": {
    "allowAdvancedCorrect": "true",
    "enableSignWithNotary": "true",
    "allowCorrect": "true"
},
"anySigner": null,
"envelopeLocation": "current_site",
"isDynamicEnvelope": "false"}
```

Then I try to POST the following JSON :

```
({{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes)

{
   "templateId": "ba205a58-9bdc-4de3-82ad-26a432d93966",
   
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Anything I might be missing?

Comment: Do you get the error for the first or second call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
POST ({{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes)

{
   "templateId": "ba205a58-9bdc-4de3-82ad-26a432d93966",
   
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Try this:

```
PUT ({{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}

{
    "status": "sent"
}
```